# how do I synchronize with server

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This must be a typical situation: as user launches my app, I need to synchronize a number of different data types with the server. I was thinking of using AsyncTask for each call. But not wanting one call to wait for another, I do

```
.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
```

My hope is that if I make twenty of these calls in a row, not one will wait for the other. Of course, do assume each call is by a different AsyncTask such as DogAsyncTask, CatAsyncTask, etc.

So here I have many questions:

- **How do I set the size of AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR so that I know 20 calls won't queue up?**
- Is AsyncTask reliable?

Comment: Why not call a REST service to send data and return json with new data.

Comment: I am not even sure how to ask you to elaborate on what you just said @JamesBlack

Comment: Why can't you just make one http call (in one AsyncTask) to ask for the 20 things at the same time? Yes, AsyncTask is reliable. Why are you even asking that?

Comment: PLEASE, everyone, image there are some restrictions on the server such that I cannot make one call and get all the different data types that I need.

Comment: What you're describing is really hard to imagine. It would be easier for me to imagine that you just don't know how to get all those different data types at the same time, so you're asking us for a roundabout way of doing what you want instead of attacking the problem directly (at least, that's what I'm imagining, I don't know if it's true). In any case, assuming what you're saying is indeed correct, the best practice would be to use another server (your own if you must) to sync up all that data before the phone asks for it. This would minimize the time its antenna has to be powered.

Comment: The main constraint on a phone is its battery consumption, that is why great care must be taken when syncing information. And it's not really the amount of data that is a factor in battery consumption (although that plays a part), it's the actual amount of time a particular antenna has to be powered on that is the most important, so great care must be taken to combine all your requests to do all of them at the very same time (as fast as the connection will allow).